# Running Python script from terminal and vim gives different output

Tags: python-3.x, vim

I'm trying to learn python and have stumbled onto a problem.

The following script fetches stock data for a specific time period and exports it to a CSV file. The CSV file is then read and plotted, all using pandas.
While running the script from terminal I get the output as desired (with dates in x axis) but executing from VIM displays row numbers in x axis.

**What could possibly be causing this?**

Run from terminal - `python3 filename.py`

Run from vim - `:w !python3`

Checking the python version on VIM and terminal both returns `python 3.6.9`

[Different Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0i3k.png)

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)

df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
df.to_csv('/home/arjun/Documents/PyScripts/Fin/tesla.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('tesla.csv', parse_dates=True,index_col=0)
df2.plot()
plt.show()
#print(df2.head())
#print(df2.info())
#print(df.head())
```

Comment: Command line equivalent for vim's `:w !python3` is `python3 < filename.py`. Try it in command line.

Comment: Obtained the same result. Command line result showed dates on x axis while Vim results did not. This seems very confusing to me!